# How to mention a specific member of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know there are other questions like this, but they are yet to satisfy me. How would would go about mentioning specific members of a set. For instance, if I wanted to mention the third element from set P. P = {1,2,3}. The third element would be 3. How would one go about notating this?

Comment: The sets are unordered, but is ok if you say the third element of  $(1,2,3)$

Comment: You may want to think of a *sequence* rather than a set. The sequence $\{a_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has first element $a_1$, second element $a_2$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that "the third element of a set" makes no sense -- recall that
$$\{1,2,3\} = \{3,1,2\} = \{ 3,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,1,2,3,1,2\} $$

What you are referring to by the "third element" is not of the set at all, but of the specific notation you have chosen to write the set.

If you wanted to refer to $3$, you would just say "$3$". Or if you had a variable $x$ and just wanted to say it is in the set $S$, you could just write that: "$x \in S$". Sometimes other things can make sense too; e.g. you might talk about the second smallest element of your set $P$, which would be $2$.

If you want a data structure that contains a bunch of elements and you want it to be meaningful to talk about actual positions within the data structure, some options are:

- A tuple; e.g. the ordered triple $(1,2,3)$.
- Sequences; e.g. the three-term sequence $P$ given by $P_i = i$ for $i \in \{ 1, 2, 3\} $
- Functions; e.g. the${}^*$ function $P$ on the domain $\{ 1,2, 3\}$ given by $P(i) = i$

*: I'm sloppy here and didn't specify a codomain. Don't take "the" too literally, unless it's appropriate for whatever definition of function you're actually using.